# Mongodb Realm, registerUser is undefined, Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, realm

I followed the docs,
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/node/manage-email-password-users/#node-manage-email-password-users

```
app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser(email, password);
```

It complains `registerUser` is undefined.

By following the type interface, I tried `realmApp.auth.emailPassword.registerUser`, it complains `registerUser` is not a function.

I have checked `email/password` user authentication, which is `on`.

Can anyone tell me what could possibly go wrong here?

I couldn't find any example that is using Node.js to register a user with email and password.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The docs should be updated to `realmApp.auth.emailPassword.registerEmail(email, password)`;